# Shortcut to open specific file in Vim?

Tags: vim

Is there a way to configure a shortcut within my `.vimrc` to automatically open a specific file in a new buffer? I have a file I frequently need to access and I would like to quickly open said file in a new buffer during a coding or writing session. I am not looking for a fuzzy search such as could be achieved with Command-T or PeepOpen, but rather a fast command to open a specific file in a new buffer. Bonus points if there is a way to control the shape of the new buffer window.

Comment: What's wrong with `:e`, `:split`, `:vsplit` or `:tabopen`?

Comment: The file I want to open is not close to my working directory. Using `:e` would be a huge pain because I would have to type out a long path to the file.

Comment: @dr.bunsen regarding long path: you can always use tab to autocomplete the path patterns.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create a mapping like:

```
nmap <leader>v :e ~/.vimrc<CR>
```

Now if you hit <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> in normal mode, it opens your `.vimrc`.

**Note**: <kbd>\</kbd> is the default leader setting, you can change with

```
let leader="WHATEVER_KEY_PREFIX_YOU_PREFER"
```

in your `.vimrc` too.

If you want in a new buffer, just try:

```
nmap <leader>v :find ~/.vimrc<CR>
```

Comment: If you want to the file to open immediately you would put a <cr> behind the command - at least I have to do it to make it work. Otherwise the command will only be put into the command-line and I still have to execute it.

Comment: Ideally, I would also like the file to be open in it's open buffer, not the current buffer.

Comment: @Gjallar thanks for pointing this out. @dr.bunsen see my update on using `:find`. Or you can use `:badd YOURFILE` but then the new file/buffer will be opened in the background.

Comment: I have a bunch of scratch buffers mapped this way `nmap ,x0 :e e:/work/scratch0.txt<CR>` for 0-9 where `,` is my leader.

Answer (score 4):

I use uppercase marks for frequently opened files.  You can use uppercase marks as bookmarks for specific files.  For example:

- `mV` — bookmark the current file.
- `'V` — go to the file bookmarked by `mV`.

Comment: Note this only works properly, if your `viminfo` settings are set up to remember global bookmarks. And if you accidentally redifine `V` you can jump to some other universe... I mean file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> :e $MYVIMRC

On startup, $MYVIMRC env. variable is defined where your .vimrc path is.