# Shortcut to open a specific file in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I want to be able to use a keyboard shortcut to edit my .emacs file instead of typing <kbd>Ctrl-X</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-F</kbd>.emacs<kbd>Enter</kbd> every time (here's [an analogous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079490/shortcut-to-open-specific-file-in-vim) regarding Vim). There's probably an obvious way of doing this, but I can't find the Emacs Lisp command to open a file. I'd think it would be something beginning with "open" or "file" but typing <kbd>M-x</kbd> and those terms doesn't seem to bring up anything relevant. I tried

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f6>") (find-file "~/.emacs"))
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: Oleg has provided a solution. Note that what you were *attempting* was to take the value *returned* by the `find-file` function (it will return a buffer object) when called with the argument `"~/.emacs"`, and then assign that buffer object as a function to call when typing `<f6>`.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

According to the documentation

> (global-set-key KEY COMMAND)
>
> Give KEY a global binding as COMMAND. COMMAND is the command
>   definition to use; usually it is a symbol naming an
>   interactively-callable function.

So you have to use an interactively-callable function:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f6>") (lambda() (interactive)(find-file "~/.emacs")))
```

Personally I prefer to use [emacs registers](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Registers.html) to store files which I use often. 
I would store '~/.emacs' in a register:

```
(set-register ?e (cons 'file "~/.emacs"))
```

and open it with  `C-x r j e`

Comment: For ~/.emacs (or in my case, ~/.emacs.d/init.el), you can use the variable user-init-file, which is always whatever user config file was loaded.  (find-file (or user-init-file ""))

Comment: Thanks a lot Oleg. Registers are great! You can even use upper- and lowercase letters, as in: `(set-register ?x (cons 'file "~/.xinitrc"))` and `(set-register ?X (cons 'file "~/.Xresources"))`.

Answer (score 6):

Bookmarking is an excellent solution for this purpose that is packaged with emacs.
That way if it's ok for you to see the list of files that you want to open, you can easily browse them.  There is also [BookmarkPlus](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) which offers variety of options.

`M-x list-bookmarks`